# Trying to deserialize LocalDateTime throws strange errors

Tags: java, angular, date, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am passing from `frontend` - Angular 4 the array of objects in which some of them are `date` objects which in `backend` there are mapped as `LocalDateTime`. Unfortunately when I try to `deserialize` by my own deserializator I got an error which is quite obvious for me but I can't solve it. So my `java` classes looks like:

`Deserializator`:

```
public class DateDeserialization extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      return LocalDateTime.parse(jsonParser.getText());
    }
}
```

My `model` class in which I add above `deserializator` to the field:

```
   @JsonFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserialization.class)
    private LocalDateTime insertDate;
```

And my `java controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<Guide> save(@RequestBody List<Guide> guides) {
    guides.stream().forEach(x -> {
        guideService.save(x);
    });
    return null;
}
```

The `error` which I get is a `404 bad request` and `error message` is:

```
JSON parse error: Text '{' could not be parsed at index 0; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException
```

Of course I know what does it mean but how to solve it? I also tried browser debugger what is passing to the backend when the request is send and:

```
0:{id: 1, description: "test1", insertDate: {…}, insertedBy: {…}, updateDate: {…}, …}
1:{id: 2, description: "test12", insertDate: {…}, insertedBy: {…}, updateDate: {…}, …}
2:{id: 3, description: "test13", insertDate: {…}, insertedBy: {…}, updateDate: {…}, …}
3:{id: 4, description: "test14", insertDate: {…}, insertedBy: {…}, updateDate: {…}, …}
4:{id: 5, description: "test15", insertDate: {…}, insertedBy: {…}, updateDate: {…}, …}
```

UPDATE:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.guideService.getAll()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.guides = res.json();
      });
  }

  save(){
    this.guideService.insertOrUpdate(this.guides).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("test went")
    });
  }
```

Comment: So it seems to be an angular issue, not sending the correct JSON and not a Java issue, no?

Comment: I have added my post with how I get data from server and then how I pass it to the backend. I don't see any error here...:(

Comment: The parse error seems to indicate an error in the JSON, not in Java. You should check the JSON content when the error occurs.

Comment: @bielas `res.json();` should work fine - maybe the content of `res` is not what you think it is.

Comment: But I’m not creating a JSON by my own. I just pass the object to the service which communicates with the backend

Comment: @assylias what do you mean by res is not what I am think it is?